# How to make flake8 fail if a plugin is not installed?

Tags: python, flake8

I use `flake8` + `flake8-docstrings` for enforcing the style guide in one of my projects. My `pre-commit` git hook has this line in it, so that it fails if `flake8` finds something:

```
flake8 --config=setup.cfg ./ || exit 1
```

But if my code has errors in docstring formatting and `flake8-docstrings` is not installed, this hook silently passes, even if I specify `--select=flake8-docstrings` or `--select=non-existing-plugin`.

I've read `--help`, `man`, online docs and Google, it looks like such functionality doesn't exist.

Am I correct? Should I post a feature request? Does it make sense to add cludges to my `pre-commit` script, such as `grep`ing `flake8 --help` for `flake8-docstrings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently there is no such feature -- but in flake8 5.x (the next released version) there will be a (name pending) `--require-plugins` option

your best bet at the moment is to either (1) search `pip freeze` for `flake8-docstrings` (2) search flake8's `--version` output for `flake8-docstrings`

```
$ pip freeze | grep flake8-docstrings
flake8-docstrings==1.6.0
$ flake8 --version | grep flake8-docstrings
4.0.1 (flake8-docstrings: 1.6.0, pydocstyle: 6.1.1, mccabe: 0.6.1,
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thank you for quick response and this future feature, I appreciate it. When this option comes out, I'll suggest an edit to your answer to mention its final name + usage + miminal `flake8` version, If I don't forget.

Comment: For future readers: exactly how Anthony said,`flake8` has `--require-plugins` option since 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using `flake8 --version | grep -q 'flake8-docstrings' || exit 1` for now.

Also, I've discovered an existing feature request [#283](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/283). Readers will probably find future news there.